# Libgdx shaperenderer circle draws as triangle due to scaling

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Im trying to create rounded squares in Libgdx
I have drawn the squares fine and now doing the rounded corners using a circle for each corner

[image]

```
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(color);
//draw horizontal square
        shapeRenderer.rect(
                (x - ((BLOCK_SIZE / 2) + 5f) / Config.DPI),
                (y - ((BLOCK_SIZE / 2) + 0) / Config.DPI),
                (width + 10) / Config.DPI,
                height / Config.DPI);
//draw vertical square
        shapeRenderer.rect(
                (x - ((BLOCK_SIZE / 2) + 0) / Config.DPI),
                (y - ((BLOCK_SIZE / 2) + 5f) / Config.DPI),
                (width) / Config.DPI,
                (height + 10f) / Config.DPI);


        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
//draw first circle (bottom left)
        shapeRenderer.circle(
                (x - ((BLOCK_SIZE / 2) / Config.DPI)),
                (y - ((BLOCK_SIZE / 2)/ Config.DPI)),
                5/Config.DPI
        );
```

on Expected result `Config.DPI = 2;`

on Actual Result `Config.DPI = 20;`


Really I need DPI to be on atleast 50, but the circle completely dissappears then.

Its the scaling, but is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another `circle` method with one additional parameter at the end for number of segments.

Comment: Worked for me thnx